# React app fails compile when using image url in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to add a background image to a control in a ReactJS project, using css and it's url functionality.

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(../images/image.jpeg); 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    color: 6b6b6b;
}
```

However, a loader is breaking, as it's trying to parse the binary file. An unexpected char. Removing the background line, and all works.

I am using webpack, and my modules are loaded like this:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                rules: [
                  {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
                  }
                ]
              }
        ]
    }
```

How can I get my react app to work with this css image as a background url? Creating the project with create-react-app - it works, but I can't see how it's handling the images.

I have a repo:
https://github.com/CraigInBrisbane/ReactLearning

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `url("../images/image.jpeg")`? Note the quotation marks.

Comment: I can try that, but it worked that way (without quotes) when I created the project using create-react-app. Now, creating a project structure manually, creating my own webpack.config etc... and pulling in the modules I think I need - fails. Same css.

Comment: Have you tried to use `url-loader`?

Comment: Oh! No, I'll look that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `css-loader`, webpack removes all your `background-image: url(../images/image.jpeg);` and inserts `require(../images/image.jpeg)`. There is two way to solve this problem: 
1) add `file-loader/url-loader` for these types of files 
2) use absolute path instead of relative ( `background-image: url(/images/image.jpeg);` ) and css-loader will skip this image